# How does a slave Powerdns server know that a domain is fresh?

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

Where/how does a slave Powerdns server know that a domain is fresh when using the Bind backend?

With the mysql backend there is a 'last_check' field: 
http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/wiki/fields

But I can't find anything similar for the Bind backend.

Example scenario: The expire field from the SOA record says that the domain's data should expire in 24 hours. Now the master server goes down. Slave should still serve data for 24 hours. What if I restart the slave after 22 hours? Will it still work 2 or again 24 hours?

If 2 hours, then how would it know that?

ps. Judging by my quick tests Powerdns doesn't invalidate such domain's data even after the expiry time is exceeded. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions, I'll answer them both.

1) the BindBackend keeps last_check in memory. You cannot currently interrogate bindbackend to see last_check - feel free to file a ticket at http://wiki.powerdns.com/ if you have a need for this feature.

2) PowerDNS ignores SOA expiry and thus your domain will keep working